persist update after event
when making a POST on the front, I need to update another entity:
@event.listens_for(Session, 'after_flush', once=True)
def update_related_entities_after_insert(session, context):
    from teacher.models.course_progress import CourseProgress
    from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import set_committed_value
    for target in session.new:  
        if isinstance(target, ApprovedResponse):
            print("entrou")

            if hasattr(target, "open_question_card_id"):
                print("entrou nesse if")
                course_progress = CourseProgress.query.filter_by(course_id=target.course_id).first()
                course_progress.concluded = False
                set_committed_value(course_progress, 'concluded', False)
                db.session.add(course_progress)
    
                print(course_progress.concluded, "concluded")

O print me informa que esse valor foi alterado, porem não altera no banco e me gera um aviso:
Consider using set_committed_value() within inner-flush event handlers to avoid this warning. site:stackoverflow.com
Try using commit() but without success, as well as other events.

Part of your question is not in English (namely "O print me informa que esse valor foi alterado, porem não altera no banco e me gera um aviso"). This is an English-only site, can you please [edit] the question.
